# svelte: how to show prop id of each element inside a list

Tags: bind, svelte-3

I'm using svelte-accesible-accordion class for Accordeons. Now i try to get the dynamic id-prop of each AccordionItem.

```
<script>
import { Accordion, AccordionItem } from "svelte-accessible-accordion";

let id;
</script>

<Accordion>
<AccordionItem bind:id title="Title 1 {id}">Content 1</AccordionItem>
<AccordionItem bind:id title="Title 2 {id}">Content 2</AccordionItem>
<AccordionItem title="Title 3">Content 2</AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

the result is, that {id} is allways shows the last id on every items. how can i get the id of each AccordionItem. I tried with bind:this={id}

Sorry, i'm on svelte-learning-modus,-)
thanks

[svelte accesible accordion class](https://github.com/metonym/svelte-accessible-accordion)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your ids in an array instead

```html
<script>
let ids = []
</script>
<AccordionItem bind:id={ids[0]} title="Title 1 {ids[0]}">Content 1</AccordionItem>
<AccordionItem bind:id={ids[1]} title="Title 2 {ids[1]}">Content 2</AccordionItem>
```